# Set Theory: Symmetric Relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If relation S1 is symmetric, prove that S1 circle S1^(-1) is also a symmetric relation.

(x,y)inS and (y,x)inS.

Thank you for help!

Comment: It's very hard to help without knowing what exactly do you need help with.

Comment: A relation R on a set S1 is symmetric provided that for every x and y in S1 circle S1^(-1) we have x(S1 circle S1^(-1))y if y(S1 circle S1^(-1))x.

Comment: How is that suppose to clarify to me in what sort of way you expect to be helped?

Comment: You don't need the assumption that $S_1$ is symmetric.

Comment: First I do not know how to prove that S1^(-1) has a symmetric relation.

Comment: $S_1^{-1}$ is simply $S_1$ but where the order is changed. meaning if $(a,b)$ is in $S_1$ then $(b,a)$ is in $S_1^{-1}$. Because $S_1$ is symmetric, then $(b,a)$ is in $S_1$ as well. but that means $(a,b)$ is in $S_1^{-1}$. This shows that if $(b,a)$ is in $S_1^{-1}$ then $(a,b)$ is in $S_1^{-1}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $aS_1b$, then it follows from the definition of inverse that $bS_1^{-1}a$.

$S_1 ∘ S_1^{-1} = \{(x,z) s.t \exists y: (x,y)\in S,(y,z)\in S_1^{-1}\}$

Suppose $(a,b) \in S_1 ∘ S_1^{-1}$. Then there is such a value $c$ that:

$(a,c) \in S_1$ and $(c,b) \in S_1^{-1}$.

Since $S_1$ is symmetric, then $S_1 = S_1^{-1}$ (Prove it!), so it follows that $(a,c) \in S_1$ and $(c,b) \in S_1$.

But $(a,c) \in S_1$ implies $(c,a) \in S_1$, so we know that:

$(b,c) \in S_1$ and $(c,a) \in S_1$. It follows from the definition of relation composition, that $(b,a) \in S_1 ∘ S_1 = S_1 ∘ S_1^{-1}$.